# What are the requirements to obtain the ATP license in Canada?

Tags: flight-training, airline-pilot, transport-canada

How much exams does a person need to do in Canada do become a ATP pilot and how many hours will be needed to become a pilot, for example ground school time, flight hour time etc....

Answer (score 1):

The requirements for ATP Aeroplane are in [CAR 421.34](https://tc.canada.ca/en/corporate-services/acts-regulations/list-regulations/canadian-aviation-regulations-sor-96-433/standards/standard-421-flight-crew-permits-licences-ratings-canadian-aviation-regulations-cars#421_34). You can read the details yourself, but in summary:

- Be at least 21 years old
- Hold a Category 1 medical
- Pass 3 written exams
- Hold a Commercial Pilot Licence - Aeroplane (valid for both day and night flight)
- Have 1500hrs total time, of which at least 900 must be in aeroplanes (see the regulation for more details on night, XC and instrument time)
- Within the last 12 months, demonstrate instrument flight and emergency procedures in a multi-engined aeroplane